# Solving equation with FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

I have:

```
(tabab = 
Table[{a -> aa, 
  First@FindRoot[
    Sum[n (E^(-beta/n - aa n))/(Sum[
          E^(-beta/n - aa n), {n, 3, 12}]), {n, 3, 12}] - 
     6, {beta, 35}]}, {aa, 0, 30, 0.15}]) // TableForm;
```

It gives me the error: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified
by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this produce what you want?

```
res = Table[{a -> N[aa],
   First@FindRoot[
     Sum[n (E^(-beta/n - aa n))/
         (Sum[E^(-beta/n - aa n), {n, 3, 12}]),
       {n, 3, 12}] - 6,
     {beta, 35}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]},
  {aa, 0, 30, 15/100}] // TableForm
```

Changes here are converting `0.15` to `15/100` for increased precision and using `WorkingPrecision` option for 20 digits of precision while running `FindRoot`.

---

Plotting the result in this form is just `ListLinePlot` with a replacement rule for `{a, beta}`... but this is almost a straight line:

```
ListLinePlot[{a, beta} /. res]
```

[image]

You can perform a straight line fit on this data and subtract it from the `beta` part, and see that it's not entirely straight (but note the differing scale):

```
With[{data = {a, beta} /. res},
 With[{fit = Fit[data, {a, 1}, a]},
  ListLinePlot[{a, beta - fit} /. res]]]
```

[image]